# Force notebook to not display dataframe when changing it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am creating a Jupyter notebook that i want to be more readable.
When changing the dataframes, they are automatically displayed in the notebook.
For instance:

```
df.drop(['street','address','district'], axis = 1)
```

Displays the whole dataframe after the change. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: Assign it back to `df` instead of just "changing it". `df = df.drop(['street','address','district'], axis=1)`

Comment: fwiw, if you are not re-assigning `df = ...`, nor setting `inplace=True`, you are actually not changing the DataFrame, only an intermediate representation of it that is later lost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you used is "Calling" the DataFrame.
Instead, you should assign the value, **try something like:**

```
df = df.drop(['street','address','district'], axis = 1)
```